# Multiple ACLs in Squid Proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

Here is my Squid configuration file.

I would like to give specific users access to specific web content,
But through this configuration file, if I give permission for a specific user to access the tutorial, social networking is blocked but movie is accessible. Even if I grouped allow and deny separately and checked, the same problem continues; I can't grant access to the tutorial but still block access to movies

```
acl localnet src 10.1.1.0/24
acl special src "/etc/squid/special.txt" # All Access IPs
acl unlimited src "/etc/squid/unlimited.txt"        # Full Download access
acl allow_proxy src "/etc/squid/allow_proxy.txt"    # Allow Proxy sites
acl allow_social src "/etc/squid/allow_social.txt"  # Allow Social networking

acl allow_tutorial src "/etc/squid/allow_tutorial.txt"  # Allow Tutorial
acl allow_movie src "/etc/squid/allow_movie.txt"    # Allow Jobs
acl allow_jobs src "/etc/squid/allow_jobs.txt"      # Allow Movie

#Allow / Block
acl goodkey url_regex "/etc/squid/goodkey.txt"
acl proxy url_regex "/etc/squid/proxy.txt"
acl social url_regex "/etc/squid/social.txt"
acl tutorial url_regex "/etc/squid/tutorial.txt"
acl movie url_regex "/etc/squid/movie.txt"
acl jobs url_regex "/etc/squid/jobs.txt"

#Download Limit
reply_body_max_size 3000 KB localnet !unlimited
request_body_max_size 3000 KB localnet !unlimited

#Allow
http_access allow special
http_access allow goodkey

#Proxy
http_access allow allow_proxy
http_access deny proxy

#Social
http_access allow allow_social
http_access deny social

#Tutorial
http_access allow allow_tutorial
http_access deny tutorial

#Movie
http_access allow allow_movie
http_access deny movie

#Jobs 
http_access allow allow_jobs
http_access deny jobs

#ACL Allow
http_access allow localnet

#And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
```

Answer (score 1):

You must combine your ACLs on a single `http_access` line like this:

```
http_access allow allow_tutorial tutorial
http_access deny allow_tutorial
```

By setting ACLs this way you are telling squid:

1. If any IP from ACL `allow_tutorial` tries to visit any URL from ACL `tutorial` **allow it**
2. If any IP from ACL `allow_tutorial` tries to visit any URL **deny it**